# Get Active Session from other computer. to know who is login

Tags: php, session, laravel, authentication

Is there any way to know who is logged in from session?

```
$user = Session::get('s_user');
```

I'm using Laravel, and that code just for one computer.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, because that is not how the session works. 
What you could do is to keep track of sessions in a database. For things like that it makes sense to use a nosql database like redis.

Comment: if I'm using database to save user status. (edit status if login).
how can i change again to logout if session expired?
any idea?

Comment: That is rather hard to do. Php does not handle the session timeout in any meaningful way.

Comment: You would have to keep track of the user's last action in your session data, and have a scheduled task to periodically switch users from "logged in" to "logged out" based on the elapsed time since last action

Comment: hmm... that's good idea..
it's like "log".
so i need new table with field. 
  id,  user,  action, create_at.
any suggestion?